# Getter isn't returning anything when I try to print using the get method

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, return

I have created a object in the main class and gave all the relevant parameters to the constructor in the "member" class.
But, when I tried to print the name by calling the getName() it prints a empty space...

Any tips would be helpful

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Name :");
    String nameInput=input.nextLine();
    input.next();
    System.out.print("Number : ");
    String number=input.nextLine();
    input.next();
    try {
        System.out.println("Type: \n 1/2/3...?");
        int choice=input.nextInt();
        switch (choice){
            case 1:{
                member object1=new member(nameInput,number);
                System.out.println("Default name : "+object1.getName());

            } case 2:{
                //this is just a sample print
                System.out.println("Case 2 selected");
            } case 3:{
                System.out.println("Case 3 selected");
            } default:{
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
   }catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Error");
        input.next();
```

This is the member class

```
public class member {
    private String Name;
    private String Number;

    public member(String name, String number) {
        Name = name;
        Number = number;
    }
    public String getName() { return Name; }
    public String getIDNumber() { return Number;}
}
```

Comment: I do not immediately see why there should be anything wrong with the getName() method. The first thing to do would be to check with a debugger what nameInput is after it is assigned. Any integrated development environment like Eclipse or IntelliJ or Netbeans would allow you do to this. You should probably set a breakpoint in the line where the assignment happens, then run in the debugger up to that point and single-step while observing the state of the relevant variables.

Comment: Your code 1) contains a lot of violations of the Java Naming Conventions, and 2) it doesn't compile. Please provide the correct code snippets.

Comment: I'm sorry for the constructor name. I changed the class name before posting this question but forgot to change the constructor name accordingly. Please take a look again I have edited it!

Comment: Again: 1) Code doesn't compile; 2) it's not complete; 3) You can't use a Type, as a variable name/identifier, like you have in `member Object=new member(nameInput,number);` (`Object` is a class in Java); 3) your `catch` block is incomplete. You have a lot of mistakes, please try to provide a correct working code.

Comment: Oh!! I didn't see that one either..these mistakes happened bcoz I tried to change my initial variable names and object names before posting this question. Can you please forget about my silly mistakes and take a look!!

Comment: Java naming conventions have classes begin with an upper case letter (Member), whereas variables and methods begin with lower case letters (name).

Comment: Why didn't you use default builtin `Scanner` class in java to input strings and numbers via keyboard input ? .

Answer (score 2):

The custom constructor must be the same exact name as the class name(upper and lower case included), also in the case 1 of the switch you named the object with the **keyword Object** , try changing those things!!

Comment: I'm sorry for the constructor name. I changed the class name before posting but forgot to change the constructor name. Please take a look again I have edited it!

Comment: Try changing the name of the object that you instantiated

Comment: Now that I see, did you import the scanner library and created the object before? bc I see the input scanner but not the code where your create it

Comment: Scanner object was initialized before this code snippet

Comment: Try to paste the first block of code you posted inside a method, for eg. : `public static void execute() {}` , also paste your member class on a separate file and just in case, try catching a general exception in the catch{ }

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your constructor. Constructor is a special method where name match with class name. and please use uppercase for class name